# Patching imported functions in a Pytest fixture

Tags: python, pytest, monkeypatching

I am having issues properly patching an imported function in pytest. The function I want to patch is a function designed to do a large SQL fetch, so for speed I would like to replace this with reading a CSV file. Here is the code I currently have:

```
from data import postgres_fetch
import pytest

@pytest.fixture
def data_patch_market(monkeypatch):
    test_data_path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'test_data')
    if os.path.exists(test_data_path):
        mock_data_path = os.path.join(test_data_path, 'test_data_market.csv')
        mock_data = pd.read_csv(mock_data_path)
        monkeypatch.setattr(postgres_fetch, 'get_data_for_market', mock_data)


def test_mase(data_patch_market):
    data = postgres_fetch.get_data_for_market(market_name=market,
                                              market_level=market_level,
                                              backtest_log_ids=log_ids,
                                              connection=conn)

    test_result= build_features.MASE(data)
```

However when I run this test I am getting a type error about calling a DataFrame:

```
TypeError: 'DataFrame' object is not callable
```

I know the csv can be read properly as I've tested that separately, so I assume something is wrong with how I am implementing the patch fixture, but I can't seem to work it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here, your call to `monkeypatch.setattr` is *replacing* any call to `postgres_fetch.get_data_for_market` with a *call* to `mock_data`.

This *can't* work since `mock_data` is not a function - its a `DataFrame` object.

Instead, in your call to `monkeypatch.setattr`, you need to pass in a *function* that returns the mocked data (i.e. the `DataFrame` object).

Hence, something like this should work:

```
@pytest.fixture
def data_patch_market(monkeypatch):
    test_data_path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'test_data')
    if os.path.exists(test_data_path):
        mock_data_path = os.path.join(test_data_path, 'test_data_market.csv')
        mock_data = pd.read_csv(mock_data_path)

        # The lines below are new - here, we define a function that will return the data we have mocked
        def return_mocked(*args, **kwargs):
            return mock_data
        monkeypatch.setattr(postgres_fetch, 'get_data_for_market', return_mocked)
```

Comment: Ah excellent thank you!
I had only used the `unittest.mock` decorator before which directly specifies the return value, so I was under the impression `setattr` worked in a similar way, but this makes perfect sense